# MVVM way to wire up event handlers in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, events, mvvm, prism

Using an MVVM pattern in Silverlight/WPF, how do you wire up event handers?  I'm trying to bind the XAML *Click* property to a delegate in the view model, but can't get it to work.

In other words, I want to replace this:

```
<Button Content="Test Click" Click="Button_Click" />
```

where Button_Click is:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    // ...
}
```

with this:

```
<Button Content="Test Click" Click="{Binding ViewModel.HandleClick}" />
```

where HandleClick is the handler.  Attempting this throws a runtime exception:

> Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MVVM way to do so is by using commands and the [`ICommand` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx).
The `Button` control has a property named `Command` which receives an object of type `ICommand`

A commonly used implementation of `ICommand` is [Prism's `DelegateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx). To use it, you can do this in your view model:

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        DoSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand(HandleDoSomethingCommand);
    }

    private void HandleDoSomethingCommand()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Then in XAML:

```
<Button Content="Test Click" Command={Binding DoSomethingCommand} />
```

Also, make sure that the viewmodel is set as your view's DataContext. One way to do so is in your view's code-behind:

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) is a good place to start if you want to know more about MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the extensions provided by Microsoft in the [Prism](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=28950) framework.  With the DLLs *System.Windows.Interactivity.dll* and *Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll*, it's possible to bind an event to a handler method in a view model:

```
<Button Content="Test Click"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"      
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding ViewModel}" MethodName="HandleClick" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: I'd say that this method should probably be used for events other than `Click`, since the `Button` control already has the `Command` property which makes it much easier (and probably more correct) to use for `Click` events.